# pdf table to frame in R via clipboard

Tags: r, pdf, import

I'm trying to copy data from a pdf into R through the clipboard (in Windows) and I keep ending up with flattened, one dimensional data.

For example, if a copy a 3x3 table from a pdf it looks like this in the clipboard:

```
Date
Name
ShoeSize
3/12/1967
Steve
8
5/12/1969
Martha
6
```

If I try something like:

```
foo <- read.table("clipboard")
```

as expected I get a frame with one variable.  I don't see an option to specify the number of columns.

`matrix()` would let me specify the number of columns but wants only numbers.

I think my best bet is to save the clipboard to a text file (say test.txt) and then use the `scan()` function, with the "what" option, like:

```
foo <- scan("test.txt", what = list(???))
```

but I am at a loss as to what to put for "what" even after reading (bits of) `scan()`'s help page and things I've tried so far have yielded garbage.  So hopefully this question boils down to: what goes in "what"?

Thanks in advance!

**SECOND EDIT: nice solution**

If you highlight the data and right click on it in Adobe Acrobat DC (or whatever the reader is now called)  there is an option "Export selection as..." which lets you save it as a csv, and that seems to be a good solution.

**EDIT: kludgy solution**

Well, if someone comes across this here's how I got this to work.  Using the above example where the clipboard is saved to test.txt, do this:

```
foo <- scan("test.txt", what= list("","",""),skip=3)
```

where there is one `""` for each column you want and the skip skips the column names.  This will give you a list that looks like:

```
>foo
[[1]]
[1] "3/12/1967" "5/12/1969"

[[2]]
[1] "Steve"  "Martha"

[[3]]
[1] "8" "6"
```

and from there you can decompose the list into named vectors:

```
> date <- foo[[1]]
> name <- foo[[2]]
> shoe <- foo[[3]]
```

and then make a data frame:

```
> bar <- data.frame(date,name,shoe)
```

and away you go!  Un-elegant, I'm sure there is a beautiful one liner that will do this, but this works.

Comment: Have a look at the package `pdftools`. That might help you a bit further.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  From what I can see pdftools looks to be more for processing entire pdfs.  I have a 90 page pdf and I only want one 9x30 table.  But maybe good if I end up having to do a lot of these, thanks!

Comment: Could you provid an example of a PDF for which you want to extract some tables?